# Is it possible to include a variable when calling an object

Tags: vba, for-loop

I have a code that places multiple nameboxes and labels on a userform. The code is very repetitive but i don't know how to create a for loop that changes the object im focusing on.

I've tried creating a loop with a variable that is included in the objects name like :

Me.Box(i).Top

```
For i = 1

Me.Box(i).Top = hauteur / 4
Me.Box(i).Left = (i * espace) + (i-1 * lbox)
Me.Label(i).Top = Me.Box(i).Top - 2 * hbox
Me.Label(i).Left = Me.Box(i).Left

Next i
```

(All my boxes are named box1 to box 7)

Here's what my code looks like :

```
 Me.Box1.Top = hauteur / 4                  
 Me.Box1.Left = espace                      
 Me.Label1.Top = Me.Box1.Top - 2 * hbox      
 Me.Label1.Left = Me.Box1.Left               

 Me.Box2.Top = hauteur / 4
 Me.Box2.Left = (2 * espace) + lbox
 Me.Label2.Top = Me.Box2.Top - 2 * hbox
 Me.Label2.Left = Me.Box2.Left

 Me.Box3.Top = hauteur / 4
 Me.Box3.Left = 3 * espace + 2 * lbox
 Me.Label3.Top = Me.Box3.Top - 2 * hbox
 Me.Label3.Left = Me.Box3.Left
```

etc...

I'm looking for the right syntaxe for the type of loop i'm doing !

Comment: Side note, maintaining a code base where a form has dozens of controls and they all have the default "[ControlType][Number]" names, is a royal pain in the neck. Consider using meaningful names instead, e.g. `FirstNameBox` instead of `TextBox37`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the controls collection, which will accept a string index

```
for i = 1 to 7 

    with Me.controls("Box" & i)
        .Top = hauteur / 4                  
        .Left = espace                      
     Me.controls("Label" & i).Top = .Top - 2 * hbox      
     Me.controls("Label" & i).Left = .Left  
    end with 

next i
```

Comment: your loop is ```x``` but you are using ```i``` in the block.

Comment: whoops - glad someone's awake - shame it's not me :-) Corrected, many thanks